# cdrom redirection fails on ILOM for Sun x4600 M2

Tags: redirection, optical-media, sun

We have been able to successfully redirect the ILOM on this x4600 M2 in the past, but for some reason now we are getting an error that says "CD-ROM image redirection failed to start":

[image: CD-ROM image redirection failed to start]

We have also launched the Storage Redirection service and that doesn't help. Launching it a second time to really make sure it's running shows that on the second time it can't bind to port 2121. We didn't get that message the first time, so I assume it is now listening (even though a scan with nmap doesn't show it listening.

[image: Unable to bind to port 2121]

We are using ILOM firmware version: 3.0.3.31

Comment: Please make sure that all you security softwares are off.. like symantics n all. and you have also updated version of java.

Answer (score 2):

Storage Redirection is hard to make work because `port 2121` is usually closed or behind a firewall.

Stick to `Devices` -> `CD-ROM image` to mount your ISO remotely.

Try to reset your SP. It may take a couple of tries but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using the 32 bit version of Java.